# Prevent access to Production resources using Azure Custom RBAC

Tags: azure, azure-rbac

I have one subscription which contains all Dev, Test, and Prod resources. I have created a custom RBAC role that grants access to limited azure resources. However, I want to restrict access to Production resources. Can I limit this using the wild card permissions? Are there other ways to grant access to all resources except Production resources?

Answer (score 0):

**I Tried to reproduce the same in my environment to Prevent access to production resources using Azure Custom RBAC**

I have created 3 Resource Groups like below

1. Production Environment
2. Testing Environment
3. Development Environment

[image]

Created RBAC rule like below

**Azure Portal>Subscription>Access control (IAM)>Add>custom role>Assignable scopes (Select Required RGS)**

[image: (https://i.imgur.com/rnPua7T.png)]

Assign RBAC Role Assignment to Required Users/Groups.

**Azure Portal>Subscription>Access control (IAM)>Role assignments>Add>Add Role Assignments (Select Custom Role) **

[image: (https://i.imgur.com/IMAskeS.png)]

Finally Assign the RBAC role to only Production Resource Group like below.

**Azure Portal>Resource Group>(Select your Production RG)>Access control (IAM)>Role assignments>Add>Add Role Assignment>RBAC- Custom Policy (Select RBAC Role)**

[image: (https://i.imgur.com/GLJXMV9.png)]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have more than 50 resource groups including all environments, and I am scoping my custom role at the Subscription level. So I was wondering if I can make changes to permissions rather than the scope.

Comment: Hi Vinayak S B, Create one RG for production env and move all prod resources to production RG and apply the RBAC rule to production RG.

Comment: Hi VenkatV, unfortunately, that's not an option.